# Call to undefined method App\Models\BrandCodeModell::fromRawAttributes() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called `BrandCodeModell` :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BrandCodeModell extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class, 'brand_id', 'id');
    }

    public function modell()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Modell::class, 'modell_id', 'id');
    }

    public function codeModell()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CodeModell::class, 'code_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And this is `Modell` relation with `Brand` Model :

```
public function modells()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Modell::class)->using(BrandCodeModell::class)
     ->withPivot('code_id');
}
```

When I try too add new modell to database I get this error :

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\BrandCodeModell::fromRawAttributes()
```

Here is my controller to save modell to database :

```
    $brand = Brand::where('id', $id)->first();

    $brand->modells()->detach();

    $modells = collect($request['modells']);

    $modells->each(function ($item) use ($brand) {
        if (is_null($item['name'])) return;

        $mod = Modell::firstOrCreate([
            'name' => $item['name'],
            'sort' => $item['sort']
        ]);

        $mod_code = $mod->codeModell()->firstOrCreate([
            'name' => $item['code']
        ]);

        $brand->modells()->attach($mod->id, [
            'code_id' => $mod_code->id
        ]);
    });
```

In this code, `Modell::firstOrCreate` and `$mod_code = $mod->codeModell()->firstOrCreate` will be create successfully but this part of code `$brand->modells()->attach($mod->id, ['code_id' => $mod_code->id]);` does not work.

Where is the problem ?

**Tell me if you need more details**

Comment: for pivot table to work, you have to define in both models as belongsToMany not belongs to. both relations should have belongsToMany relation try if its fix your issue.

Comment: @AbdulRehman I change it to :  return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class, 'brand_id', 'id'); but still I have the error

Comment: When I clear ->using(BrandCodeModell::class) code works fine

Comment: why you have to specify which model for relation you are using pivot table automatically know if the relation have pivot table is formed correctly if its work fine without using remove using.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models):

> Custom many-to-many pivot models should extend the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` class

So your pivot class should look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class BrandCodeModell extends Pivot
{
   //
}
```

However, unless you're adding additional methods on to the pivot class, there's no need to define it; Laravel will automatically use the appropriate pivot table. Likewise there's probably no need for it to import the `HasFactory` trait, as entries would be automatically created by related model creation.